# Writing stream `operator>>` for serial number?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a serial number class of the following form:

```
class SerialNumber { ... }
```

and I want to write the `operator>>` for it:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& i, SerialNumber& s)
{
    ???

    return i;
}
```

The serial numbers are always 19 characters long and start with a hex digit.

I am confused if I should `istream.read` 19 characters.  It may include prefix whitespace. ?

Or whether I should read a `i >> std::string` and then check that it is 19 characters long.    When you read a `std::string` it skips whitespace (is there a standard way to implement that?)  Further if I read a `std::string` it may have a valid 19 character serial number prefix, and I may have "over-read" the input. ?

**Update:**

```
inline istream& operator>>(istream& is, SerialNumber& id)
{
    ostringstream os;

    is >> ws;

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        char c;
        is >> c;
        os << c;
    }

    id = DecodeId(os.str());

    return is;
}
```

Partially sanitized version of Dietmar Kühl code:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, SerialNumber& sn)
{
    constexpr size_t n = 19;

    istream::sentry se(in);

    if (!se)
        return in;

    istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in.rdbuf()), end;

    if (it == end || !isxdigit(*it))
    {
        in.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
        return in;
    }

    string s(n,'?');
    for (size_t i = 0; it != end && i < n && !isspace(char(*it)), ++i)
            s[i] = *it++;

    sn = DecodeId(s);

    if (failed to decode)
        in.setstate(ios_base::failbit);

    return in;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific form for it? What is the full class definition? What have you tried?

Comment: Are they always *exactly* 19 chars long?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what does istream& operator>> mean? could you explain it or send an article where I could read about it?:)

Comment: @MaggiQall: It is part of the C++ standard input/output library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't clear. I meant the bitwise right shift operator>>

But I'm going to read about it:) Thank you very much

Comment: @MaggiQall: Yes the shift operators are overloaded against ostream and istream to do input and output.  Hence the C++ hello world program `cout << "Hello World"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard formatted input functions always follow the same pattern:

1. They start off with constructing a `std::sentry` object which handles any skipping of leading whitespace depending on the setting of the `std::ios_base::skipws` formatting flag.
2. The read value is unchanged if reading the value fails in any way and `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set.
3. Characters are consumed up to the first character which fails to match the format.

That is, the input function would look something like that:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, SerialNumber& s) {
    std::istream::sentry kerberos(in);
    if (kerberos) {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in.rdbuf()), end;
        char buffer[20] = {};
        int  i(0);
        if (it != end && std::isxdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))) {
            for (; it != end && i != 19
                   && !std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)); ++i) {
                buffer[i] = *it++;
            }
        }
        if (i == 19) {
            SerialNumber(buffer).swap(s);
        }
        else {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Dealing directly with the stream buffer, this is much better than my suggestion.

Comment: +1 Dietmar you spend *way* to much time reading std lib source =P Thanks for the education on `sentry`. I never knew it was even there.

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps No. The default constructor for `std::istreambuf_iteartor<char>` creates the end iterator for the sequence.

Comment: @WhozCraig: What you mean I spend too much time *reading* the std lib source? I *wrote* my [own implementation](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) of IOStreams and locales (yes, it is somewhat dated by now and may not even compile but I haven't come around putting a new implementation together).

Comment: I think this: `!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it), ++i` should be this: `!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)); ++i`

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, this is a typo: I didn't try to compile the code... (I'll fix it; there were a number of other typos, as well). Thanks!

Comment: Point 2 is correct for C++03 but is outdated with the new standard C++11. If conversion fails (for numbers at least) the value is zeroed. Formatted input uses `num_get<> (22.4.2.1)` from the local to read numbers which uses `22.4.2.1.2 num_get virtual functions` which states on failure zero is used.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Interesting. I recall lots of discussions on how to deal with overflow and underflow but I didn't notice that it eventually got fixed, especially in the way stated. Thanks for pointing this change out! Unless encoding an indication of the failure cause I'd still leave the value unchanged when failing to read. I'm pretty sure that this is still the current behavior for other formatted input functions like for `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it one step at a time:

- If you want to *always* skip whitespace, then start by doing `i >> std::ws`. The stream may not have the `skipws` flag set. Otherwise let the user decide whether to skip whitespace or not, and set the stream error bit when reading a whitespace.
- Read the first `char`, see if its an hexadecimal digit. If its not, then set the stream error bit.
- Read the rest of the 18 characters, and as soon as you find a character that does not meet the serial number format set the stream error bit.

  You should disable `skipws` for this, otherwise you will get valid results from characters separated by whitespace. If you do, then make sure to restore the `skipws` flag when exiting the function (which may happen via an exception when setting the error bit, if exceptions are enabled on the stream).

Comment: I added the code I used in an update to my Q.  If you have a comment that would be great.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos FathomlingCorps: Your implementation accepts serial numbers where some or all of their parts are separated by whitespace. And you never check for errors and set the stream error flag accordingly hence `if( is >> sn )` will always return `true` even when reading an invalid serial number...

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos FathomlingCorps: See _Dietmar Kühl_ post for a much better answer!